# What is the correct way to write MsUnit and N unit Test Cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Is it the right approach if we directly hit the database to write/excute/Run unit test cases for CRUD operation ?

Comment: you mean CRUD operation right?

Comment: To me you are talking about an **integration** test rather then a **unit** test

Comment: Yes , sorry for Mistake

Comment: its ok for integration tests but not for unit tests

Comment: Then what is the right approach to test Insert/Delete/update/get function without hit the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Testing infrastructure or data access related code is generally considered **integration** testing (as opposed to unit testing) although both approaches can be used, and a number of tools exist to facilitate unit testing of a data access layer. By their very nature, unless you choose to mock your data access layer, such tests will almost always involve some element of network access, so you end up breaking at least one of the rules of [strict unit testing](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/).

Personally I think it is perfectly ok to directly hit the database specifically to test data access code, and that there is little point in trying to turn a very valid integration test scenario into a unit test one simply to make it into a "unit test". That said, you should appreciate that this will generally incur a time penalty due to the latency of your network and will introduce other variables such as network availability that will potentially make the tests more brittle.

As some of the comments have suggested you could decide to mock your database, which is an option that may well suit your needs. However there are a number of reasons as to why this may not be advisable (see [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/writing-tests-for-data-access-code-unit-tests-are-waste/) and [here](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/26/stop-unit-testing-database-code/)), namely (taken from second link):

> You start creating an alternative system that heavily deviates from
>   your productive system. This essentially means:
>
> - that results from tests against your test system have (almost) no    meaning
> - that your tests will not cover some of the most complex    aspects of your productive system
> - that you will start spending way    too much time on tweaking tests rather than implementing useful    business logic

If you do choose to call your database directly rather than mocking it, one approach you may find useful is to take a backup of the database in question (ideally regular backups if resources permit) and run all of your integration tests against this. This way you can test your code against a good replica of your live data, without running tests against your actual live data.

Answer (score 0):

Testing CRUD is often considered a integration test. Personally, I always recommend writing automated testing for anything you could see a **logic** failure. Integration tests are a really good thing to do for end to end testing, not usually your standard CRUD. I don't usually test standard CRUD, like others have said, I usually just mock my data and focus on unit testing my logic. You **can** do integration testing using the unit testing framework to accomplish standard CRUD testing, however.

Depending on the type of database you're using a great way to go about it is to create a local database using the schema of your production database and seeding it with data in your test project. This will free you up to utilize your classes (hopefully they are repositories) to practice all the CRUD to that test database. You'd want a class that manages that test database(creating, seeding, dropping) that you can use it in the init and cleanup, respectively, of your tests. There's a few ways to skin that cat so check out [Anatomy of a Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517(v=vs.100)) and the [Assembly Initialize Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssemblyInitializeAttribute.aspx)

For the walk through how to of how to accomplish an integration along the lines of, what I'm assuming, you're interested in. Go [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833283(v=vs.100).aspx).